# shutil move sometimes changes file properties on mac

Tags: python, macos, finder, shutil

On Mac, there is the `hide extension` property on files. You can either hide/show the extension by right click > Get Info > Name & Extension > Hide Extension checkbox

I have a file whose file extension is shown, however when I use `shutil.move()` to move it elsewhere, the resulting file has its extension hidden. How do I preserve the original file extension property?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've just looked into the code of shutil from 2.7.6 and there's nothing in it what would copy extended attributes. Also there's http://bugs.python.org/issue14082. So I guess you should either use a fixed version, or handle it manually. Likely `shutil` from Python-3.3.1 installed on localhost actually copies extended attributes if `os` package contains `listxattr` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, Python does not yet support extended attributes via the `os.*xattr` functions on BSD-derived systems like OS X. See http://bugs.python.org/issue12978

Comment: Thank you for the notice. So probably the solution is `implement yourself`. Or, better, "provide a patch for upstream"